# Simple CAPTCHA for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spam, captcha

I am looking for CAPTCHA implementation or configuration in AngularJS project without using the reCAPTCHA concepts.

Comment: Well, there are a number of hits when I google `AngularJS captcha -recaptcha`, but perhaps you can tell us why you don't want to use recaptcha ?

Comment: thanks for your question, for a security reasons also we dont want to depend on any out side services.

Comment: You know as a security professional, we would recommend you to rely on accepted implementations and regularly audited and patched ones that your own custom mechanisms.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101324/is-there-anything-insecure-about-google-recaptcha

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53218/would-using-google-recaptcha-allow-google-to-cheat/53220#53220

Comment: Sorry, I intended to post the link here after creating that question, but I got called into a meeting. My reason for posting the question is that you are not getting any response here and I personally think that it would be a waste of time to implement your own system. However, I know enough to know that I don't know enough to tell you enough about the security pros & cons better than the guys over there can. I hope that their reply helps you to decide.

Comment: Can you please reply to Dezza's answer on the other question?

Comment: You don't want to rely on outside services but you're willing to use a third party CAPTCHA implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Visual Captcha](http://visualcaptcha.net/) which is self-hosted and supports AngularJS.

Check [this](https://github.com/emotionLoop/visualCaptcha) for supported front and backend

Update [31-03-2021]: This project is not actively developed anymore.